# Absolute element won't show

Tags: css

I have a div element inside a main div, which i wanted to put an image tag into it. The problem is, when i positioned the image to absolute, the image didn't show up and the container div didn't take any space on the main div. But when i remove the position:absolute the image is showing just fine. Any help how to show it without removing the position:absolute?

The code is something like this:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="image_wrapper">
    <img style="width:100%; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;" src="image.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="image_wrapper">
    <img src="image.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#image_wrapper {
position:relative;
}

#image_wrapper img {
  width:100%; 
  position:absolute; 
  top:0px; left:0px;
}
```

try this maybe it help....

Answer (score 0):

When you set an element to be `absolute`-positioned, it is removed from the flow of the document. In this case, it means the container `<div>` now has "nothing" inside it and therefore collapses to zero height.

Also note that you should almost always give the containing element `position:relative` to provide an origin for the absolute element.

The main problem, though, is the lack of height on the container. Fix that and your image should show up.

If it doesn't, then try also specifying the image's height.